# Passing Multiple Agument to fragment using TypeSafe in Navigation

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I know it is possible to pass a single argument using Action in the source fragment

```
  override fun onClick(v: View) {
       val amountTv: EditText = view!!.findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount)
       val amount = amountTv.text.toString().toInt()
       val action = SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections.confirmationAction(amount)
       v.findNavController().navigate(action)

}
```

and get that in the destination fragment as specified in android docs

```
    val args: ConfirmationFragmentArgs by navArgs()
        override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            val tv: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAmount)
            val amount = args.amount
            tv.text = amount.toString()
}
```

please let me know is there any way to pass multiple arguments in TypeSafe way

Comment: You can do that by creating an array of objects and pass to other fragment by parcelable in bundle and receive as a object in required class. Since object is typesafe it will accept it. Thanks @Asgar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you could do it by defining multiple arguments for your fragment in the Navigation graph and then pass them to the `action` in your code. This is an example:

**navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.app.FirstFragment"
        android:label="FirstFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.app.SecondFragment"
        android:label="secondFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second">
        <argument
            android:name="firstDataList"
            app:argType="com.example.app.domain.FirstData[]" />
        <argument
            android:name="secondDataList"
            app:argType="com.example.app.domain.SecondData[]" />

        <argument
            android:name="isOkey"
            app:argType="boolean" />
        <argument
            android:name="myString"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>


</navigation>
```

and then in your code:

You should pass the arguments respectively as it is navigation.xml

**FirstFragment.kt**

```
findNavController().navigate(
    FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment(
        firstDataList.toTypedArray(),
        secondDataList.toTypedArray(),
        isOkey,
        myString
    )
```

And then retrieve it at the destination as a `bundle` like so:

**SecondFragment.kt**

```
val args = arguments?.let {
    SecondFragmentArgs.fromBundle(
        it
    )
}
if (args != null) {
    firstDataList = args.firstDataList.toCollection(ArrayList())
    secondDataList = args.secondDataList.toCollection(ArrayList())
    isOkey = args.isOkey
    myString = args.myString

}
```

To pass complex objects you should make them `parcelable`. In my example, I passed two lists of complex models that I parcelized them like this:

**DataModels.kt**

```
@Parcelize
data class FirstData(var id: Int, var color: Int = 0) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class SecondData(var name: String, var position: ArrayList<Int>) : Parcelable
```

Comment: Thanks, But i think am having problem with auto generation of argument in the SecondFragmentArgs, First argument is generated but the second one is not. @Squti

Comment: Actually I am facing same kind of issue additionally   i am using second fragment in two navigation graph ex home_nav and dashboard_nav but direction class generate for home only then In the action there is no parameters ......do you have any idea how to solve that. { currently I copy same fragment in both xml all attribute same and it work but In this case unwanted code is added in dashboard_nav} I dont want that unwanted code there